# DS18B20 temperature sensor not found in devices folder

Tags: pi-3b+, ds18b20

I am trying to setup DS18B20 for Raspberry Pi. I have followed the instructions from Adafruit Lesson 11

1. updated RBPI kernal to 4.19
2. setup wiring (see below) with 10k resistor
3. verified signal (yellow to black) using multimeter ~ 2.4-2.6V
4. updated the config.txt file in boot directory

restarted and then ran the following code.

```
~ $ sudo modprobe w1-gpio
~ $ sudo modprobe w1-therm
~ $ cd /sys/bus/w1/devices
/sys/bus/w1/devices $ ls
/sys/bus/w1/devices $
```

there is nothing returned after the "ls" command indicating that the directory is empty. According to the instructions, if successful then I should see a device listed 28-xxxx.

[DS18B20 setup instructions from Adafruit Lesson 11](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/hardware)

wiring

DS18B20 : RBPI

red : Pin 1 (3.3V)

black : Pin 9 (GND)

yellow : Pin 7 (GPIO4)

[image: wiring setup 01]
[image: wiring setup 02]

Comment: your device black wire seems to be connected to breadboard column 19 where as the pi seems to be on 21 - also, with that mess of wires on the pi, it's hard to guess which gpio you are connecting to on the pi - there's 2 orange 2 black and 2 red on the pi - what are you connecting to?

Comment: the yellow wire from the Ds18B20 connects to the orange wire ... which you say is pin 7 - but there is no orange wire on pin 7 of the pi

Comment: A grey wire appears to be on pin 7 (GPIO 4).  Is that connected to the DS18B20 data pin?

Comment: Those instructions are ante-deluvian - nothing to do with current Raspbian

Answer (score 1):

The issue was tri-fold:

1. wiring of the pull-up resistor should be as follows: [image: wiring]
2. 1-wire protocol was OFF. Simplest way to switch that ON is through sudo raspi-config -> interfaces.
3. w1-gpio and thermal driver were missing. As soon as they were installed, sensor surfaced in /sys/bus/w1/devices/ and was producing desired output.